# Random array, showing less than 3 of the same

Tags: php, arrays, random

I am using a random PHP array for a raffle type script and I sometimes get the same string 3 or more times. How can I limit the random to only show a max of 2 of the same string?

For example I have:

```
  <?php
  $raffle = array('string1', 'string2', 'string3', 'string4', 'string5', 'string6');

  echo $raffle[array_rand($raffle)] . ", " . $raffle[array_rand($raffle)] . ", " .   $raffle[array_rand($raffle)] . ", " . $raffle[array_rand($raffle)];
  ?>
```

So it chooses a random of 4 strings from the array, but I don't want the same string to show up more than twice. How can I achieve this?

Comment: But the same one showing up twice is ok? Just not three times? Is that right?

Comment: Use a `while` loop and stop it only if the value was shown 2 times or less

Comment: @DamienBlack, yes twice is okay but not more.

Comment: @RazHarush, A while loop would work yes, but how do I make it stop the value after if its shown twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a function that will store what has been pick, and if picked again, remove it from the array. Once removed from the array, it'll never get picked again. So items can show up twice, but not more:

```
function pull_raffle() {
    static $raffle = array('string1', 'string2', 'string3', 'string4', 'string5', 'string6');
    static $pulled_before = array();

    $pick = array_rand($raffle);
    $string = $raffle[$pick];
    if (array_key_exists($string, $pulled_before)) {
        unset($raffle[$pick]);
    } else {
        $pulled_before[$string] = true;
    }

    return $string;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
echo pull_raffle() . ", " . pull_raffle(). ", " .  pull_raffle() . ", " . pull_raffle();
```

Comment: This makes sense, but the function doesn't seem to be working correctly with the static "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'static' (T_STATIC), expecting '&' or variable (T_VARIABLE)"

Comment: Should I be using the string variables outside of the function?

Comment: @Faded That would be because the 'function' is missing two key characters.

Comment: @Faded Sorry, my copy must have failed. Try it now.